# powerBi can't access database after crash

Tags: database, powerbi, crash, connexion

I'm working with powerBi and today it got a crash because my RAM got full, When I logged back in, I took the auto save backup, but when loading it I was unable to reconnect to the database, giving me this error message.

```
An error occurred while reading data from the provider:
'Unable to load the file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices,
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
Either a required identity borrowing level was not provided,
or the identity borrowing level provided is invalid.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)'
```

I looked on the internet to see any solution for my problem but I couldn't find anything similar. I investigated powerBi for a reconnexion button, but couldn't find any.

So I come here asking you help, any idea where my problem can come from?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some more research and tests, I finally found the solution.

I needed to launch powerBi Desktop as administrator.

This problem was preventing it to access the database for "to low admin level", but in a strange and complicated message.